# How to redirect ip to subdomain

Tags: redirect, ip, subdomain, cpanel

Please help me, I want set my ip public can be accessible with sub domain,

**example:** 
***172.168.165.150/sistem***
can be accessible with subdomain sistem.domain.com

How to configure that, whether using cpanel or using methods.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the subdomain tab from your cPanel home page and add a subdomain if not. In the last column of the subdomain table, there will be an option to manage redirection.

[image]